# Github Actions with gzip after build

Tags: node.js, github, yaml, github-actions

I have been trying to work out a way to gzip my build files after a build within a github action.  My build doesn't automatically do this, and I'm not sure where or when it should be zipping.

My action has a working run command that builds the project, but then the zipping either fails or just doesn't work depending on how I run it.

This is how I've tried lately:

```
- name: Build
  run: |
    npm ci
    npm run build --prod --aot

- name: GZIP
  run: |
    npm install gzip-cli
    gzip ./dist/*.js -k -9
```

I'm sure the answer here is either "you can't do that" or "you can't do that", but I don't know where to go from here.  My server does not zip the files itself and I'm not sure how to make github do it.  I need all of the `js` files to have `gz` files.

I have tried using `gzipper` as well as `gzip-cli` and the console usually outputs this:

```
  npm install gzipper
  gzipper --exclude jpg,jpeg,png,svg ./dist
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.1 requires a peer of jasmine-core@>=3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ gzipper@3.4.2
updated 1 package and audited 19029 packages in 11.676s

33 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 2 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
/home/runner/work/_temp/96763ca6-0048-4812-a8bb-72bf33d14fcc.sh: line 2: gzipper: command not found
##[error]Process completed with exit code 127.
```

It looks like it installs just fine, but then it shows the command can't be found (whether gzipper or gzip-cli).

If I were to use plain old `gzip`, I don't get any error.  It runs, but does not actually zip anything.  Could it be github is temporarily storing the files somewhere before uploading it?

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? And what do you mean it fails depending on how you run it; What other ways have did you try to run the command? Also are you sure the `gzip` command is on the path? Assuming you are doing this in a linux environment, can you run the command `command -v gzip` to see which `gzip` command (if any) you are running? Please include all these as an update to your question

Comment: @smac89 Thank you for the comment, I'll update the answer right now

Comment: You should try installing it globally. By default, if the `-g` flag isn't specified, npm will automatically install your dependency locally under `node_modules`. Dependencies with executables will have their executables available in `node_modules/.bin`, which can be found by executing `$(npm bin)`.

Comment: What runner are you using for the workflow? (e.g. `ubuntu-latest`, `macos-latest`)

Comment: @Edric I'm doing `runs-on: ubuntu-latest`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current method you're using to install `gzip-cli` or `gzipper`, they'll be saved to the current project's `node_modules` folder. Their executables will also be installed in `node_modules/.bin` (which can be found by running [`npm bin`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/bin.html)). However, your project dependency executables will typically not be available in the `PATH` environment variable unless you install them globally.

From the [docs for the `bin` field for a dependency's `package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin):

> On install, npm will symlink that file into [`prefix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#prefix-configuration)`/bin` for global installs, or `./node_modules/.bin/` for local installs.

As such, you should either:

- Install the dependencies globally with the `-g` flag. If npm's `.bin` directory is included in the `PATH`, you can easily execute the commands.
- Run the commands with `$(npm bin)/` appended to the command:

  ```sh
  $(npm bin)/gzip ./dist/*.js -k -9
  ```
- Or add a [script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) that does the same thing. Typically npm scripts will have [dependency executables available to them in the `PATH` environment variable](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#path):

  ```
  {
    "scripts: {
      "gzip-files": "gzip ./dist/*.js -k -9"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "gzip-cli": "/* version range */"
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm testing the other two bullets, but with the first bullet, it seems github doesn't allow me to install globally.  I get the messages `Run npm install gzip-cli -g
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules`.  So I will try the other two next!

Comment: Your second option worked perfectly! Thank you so much!  A quick question: Do I need to run the install every time?  I'm not exactly sure how those boxes are set up.

Comment: You could add the `gzip-cli` to your project's dependencies and it would be installed if your workflow includes a step to install the dependencies.

Comment: Huh, I thought I had that, but I'm going to have to double check. Thank you for clearing this all up!